# socket.io client - emit callback does not fire if no connection or server is down

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, client

I am trying to add some verifications client side, to be sure the message was correctly sent to the server.

If the server goes down, the callback function does not fire and I cannot tell to my client if the message was correctly delivered. The same thing happens if my client (mobile client) lose its signal.

How can I handle connection errors in my client?

Thanks for your help.

```
socket.emit('send', JSON.stringify(msg), function (res) {
    if(res)  { 
        $messages.unshift(msg); 
    }
    else { 
      $scope.$emit('triggerError',  { message: 'Unable to send your message.', temp: true });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the socket.on('disconnect', ...) callback? According to [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) documentation, this is the way to detect that a client has disconnected. Since socket.io uses web sockets, and web sockets establish an active connection, whenever the connection is lost, the socket is immediately disconnected and this callback is triggered.

I have used it in my projects and it works. I have never tried using it on the client side, but probably it works too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several events for this purpose.
You can bind on 'error' - if some error occurs you'll get this event triggered.
You can bind on 'disconnect' - you can detect disconnection from the server.